# Get height of image in 2nd LI

Tags: jquery

struggling to get the right jQuery to get the height of the image included in the 2nd LI in this code... any ideas?

```
<ul class="example">
<li><img src="example.jpg" width="500" height="500"></li>
<li><img src="example.jpg" width="500" height="500"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) *eq is zero-index based* so it starts with 0

```
$('.example li:eq(1) img').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). Try this:

```
$("ul.example li").eq(1).find("img").height();
```

or

```
$("ul.example li:eq(1) img").height();
```

Comment: @Anton: Thanks Anton. Updated :)